# Не срабатывает OnClick на кнопке

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с проблемой того, что при нажатии на кнопку событие OnClick не срабатывает. В логах нет ошибок, просто я нажимаю кнопку, а ответной реакции нет.

Объект "open".

Код:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
db = new DBHelper(this);
final Button open = findViewById(R.id.bopen);
intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, open.class);
open.setEnabled(false);
final Spinner sp = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        intent.putExtra("name", sp.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }
});
sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        open.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        open.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
SQLiteDatabase sql = db.getReadableDatabase();

Cursor cr = sql.query(DBHelper.TABLE, null,null, null, null, null, null);

if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(sql,DBHelper.TABLE);
    arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    do {
        arr.add(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.KEY_NAME)));
    } while(cr.moveToNext());
    cr.close();
    ArrayAdapter<?> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    sp.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы при нажатии на кнопку просто добавляете данные в `Intent`, вам необходимо его еще обработать (запустить).

```
startActivity(intent);
```